# Problem with captions in apa-style

Tags: captions, apa-style

the following code

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[man,floatmarkers,noapacite,latin]{apa}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}%context-sensitive quotes, required for biblatex
\usepackage{graphicx}%inclusion of images
\usepackage{lipsum}% blind text

\usepackage{hyperref}%hyperrefs in PDF, must be last package called, preloaded in beamer

\addbibresource{Project-literature.bib}


\title{My fancy, wordy title}
\shorttitle{My title}   % defaults to title
\author{John Doe}
\affiliation{Alma mater, Shangrila (Paradise)}

\abstract{\lipsum[1]}

\acknowledgements{\lipsum[2]}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
\maketitle
Keywords: a keyword, another keyword

\lipsum[3]

\begin{figure}
 \caption{A caption explaining the figure }
 \label{fig:aa}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphics/test1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4] (vide fig. \ref{fig:aa})

\begin{figure}
 \caption{Another caption explaining another figure }
 \label{fig:bb}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphics/test2}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5] (vide fig. \ref{fig:bb}).

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

produces the following list of captions with spurious “figure. #” (highlighted):
[image: Caption list produced by above LaTeX-code]

How can I get rid of them?

Comment: Since your example doesn't require `biblatex` you may want to remove that from the code.  The option for float markers is `floatmark` not `floatmarkers`. The problem is that you're loading `hyperref` and the `apa` class messes with the caption code and isn't aware of `hyperref`. So if you comment out `hyperref` the problem goes away. Whether there's a fix that allows you to use `hyperref`, I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

The `apa` class has not caught up with fact that `\contentsline` has four arguments with `hyperref` (and for a few years also with LaTeX).

Try

```
\makeatletter \long\def\@@contentsline#1#2#3#4{ #2 }\makeatother
```

and make a bug report.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this solves the problem.